# Can't access checked property of menu item created with code outside the designer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, toolstripitem

```
private void Form_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Load Settings
    this.tsmiDuplexEnabled.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.DuplexEnabled;
    this.tsmiRemoveBlanks.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.AutoDiscardBlanks;

    this.tsmiColorMode.DropDownItems[Properties.Settings.Default.ColorMode].Checked = true;
}
```

The last line does not work because it doesn't find the checked property, although there are many available properties. Any idea how I can get at that property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast it as a `ToolStripMenuItem` to get the `Checked` property.  Note that separators are not `ToolStripMenuItem` so you can't blindly cast every `DropDownItem` as a `ToolStripMenuItem`.

For example:

```
foreach (ToolStripItem tsi in item.DropDownItems)
{
    if (tsi is ToolStripMenuItem)
        ((ToolStripMenuItem)tsi).Checked = true;
}
```

In your case it looks like you won't accidentally get a separator, so this should work:

```
((ToolStripMenuItem)this.tsmiColorMode.DropDownItems[Properties.Settings.Default.ColorMode]).Checked = true;
```

Comment: Well that makes perfect sense. Thank you!